# Galaxy Gear not recognized by adb and odin after last update

Tags: debugging, usb, galaxy

Today I updated my galaxy gear to latest version and since then adb and odin are not recognizing it. I tried almost everything, changing cable, restarting, usb debugging on/off, i have no idea what could it be. 
ADB always returns an emtpy list on "adb devices" and error:no device on adb:shell.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has a problem to this, I solved it. As I updated my Galaxy Gear from android to Tizen OS, Gear is no longer listed as an android device and you can not see it by running adb command, instead you can see it by running sdb command( its available once you download tizen SDK for wearable). 
I downgraded from Tizen OS to Android OS via this method without any problem because I wanted to be able to run full APKs on my Gear.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2776157

Cheers

Comment: I tried to downgrade my samsung gear s but as i couldnt see my device using adb command i am stuck at recovery screen